# Statistics: Conditional Probability

Tags: statistics

Two tetrahedral dice are thrown; one is red and the other is blue . The number on which each lands is noted, the faces being marked 1,2,3,4. Find the probability that

a)  the sum of the numbers on which the dice lands is 6 given that the red die lands on an odd number

My solution: P(RedOdd | blue) / P(RedOdd)

RedOdd= 1,3

Blue = 2,4

2/6 * 2/6 / 2/6 = 1/3

I'm not sure if my solution is right so I will like it checked over please.

**NB: This is conditional Probability**

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. If one of the dice lands on an odd number and the sum is 6, then there is only one possibility in four for the other die. Rethink your work in light of this.

Comment: Let $P$ be the event sum is $6$ and $Q$ the event red odd. You want $\Pr(P\cap Q)/\Pr(Q)$. You did not compute $\Pr(Q)$ correctly. And your numerator seems to have nothing to do with sum is $6$.

Comment: You seem to be mixing problems together?  The proposed solution does not make sense with your stated problem.  On top of this, you are dividing by six for some strange reason.  Look at what the sample space is... $\{(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{1}), (\color{red}{1}, \color{blue}{2}), (\color{red}{1}, \color{blue}{3}), \dots,(\color{red}{4}, \color{blue}{3}),( \color{red}{4},\color{blue}{4})\}$.  Which of those have the red die as odd?  Which of *those* have the sum equalling six?

Comment: In addition to this, you write `P(RedOdd | blue) / P(RedOdd)`.  If you are trying to write what the problem is asking you to calculate, it is in fact meant to be $Pr(\text{sum=6}~|~\text{Red is odd}) = \frac{Pr(\text{Red is odd}\cap \text{sum=6})}{Pr(\text{Red is odd})}$

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the sample space is... $\{(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{1}), (\color{red}{1}, \color{blue}{2}), (\color{red}{1}, \color{blue}{3}), \dots,(\color{red}{4}, \color{blue}{3}),( \color{red}{4},\color{blue}{4})\}$.

What is the sample space size?

> $4\cdot 4=16$

Which outcomes have the red die as odd?

> The ones which start with $\text{red}1$ or $\text{red}3$.

How  many outcomes have the red die being odd?

> $2\cdot 4 = 8$

Which outcomes have an odd red die **and** the sum totaling six?

> only $(\text{red}3,\text{blue}3)$

How many of them are there?

> $1$

Now, use the following definitions for probability in an equiprobable sample space (such as this one):

> Probability of $A$ occurring $=Pr(A) = \frac{|A|}{|S|}$, where $A$ is an event, $|A|$ represents the number of outcomes in that event, $S$ represents the sample space.
>
> Probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ occurs $=Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$ which in the case of an equiprobable sample space simplifies as $=\frac{|A\cap B|}{|B|}$

Comment: So my answer will be 1/16 ?

Comment: @Ken Where did $1/16$ come from?  Read again my answer.  I took you through step by step how to get it.  $1/16$ is the probability that you get the specific outcome $(\color{red}{3},\color{blue}{3})$ when tossing the two dice without knowing anything else, but this is not the probability of getting a sum of six **given that** we know the red is odd.